# Rewrite the source address of all outgoing traffic

Tags: tcp, proxy, mitmproxy

I want to build a virtual machine that would be able to rewrite all of the network traffic that passes through it, so that the traffic appears to have a different source address. The source address we use will be different depending on the type of traffic / the destination of the traffic.

Originally, I was considering [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/), as that would be suitable for http traffic.

Note that I'm not concerned that the responses to the traffic will not be routed back to my vm.

I'm finding this problem particularly hard to Google, so I was looking to see if anyone had any recommendations.

Comment: Have you looked at iptables?  Check out --dnat.

Comment: What you describe is source NAT (SNAT).